# Why in OOP you do everything in objects?

Tags: php, oop, object

We have started to work with PHP developer, i looked at his code and from my perspective this is waste of ink to write stuff like this. I personally dont do OOP.

He never answered this question can someone who good with OOP explain.

In file **inc/path.php** you define *class Path* with different variables for path to files and folders

```
class Path
{
    var $path_cnfg = null;

    /* URLs */
    var $url_css = '';//for css url
    var $url_js = '';//for javascript url
    var $url_img = '';//for image url

    /* Paths */
    var $path_inc = '';//inc directory path 
    var $path_img = '';//image path


    function Path()
    {
        $this->path_cnfg = new Config();

        /* Setting URL(s)  */

        $this->url_css = $this->path_cnfg->base_url.'assets/css/';
        $this->url_js = $this->path_cnfg->base_url.'assets/js/';
        $this->url_img = $this->path_cnfg->base_url.'assets/img/';

        /* Setting Path(s) */

        $this->path_inc = $this->path_cnfg->root_path.'/inc/';
        $this->path_img = $this->path_cnfg->root_path.'/img/';
    }
}
```

A. Whats the purpose of method **Path** inside class path?

```
function Path()
{
    $this->path_cnfg = new Config();

    /* Setting URL(s)  */

    $this->url_css = $this->path_cnfg->base_url.'assets/css/';
    $this->url_js = $this->path_cnfg->base_url.'assets/js/';
    $this->url_img = $this->path_cnfg->base_url.'assets/img/';

    /* Setting Path(s) */

    $this->path_inc = $this->path_cnfg->root_path.'/inc/';
    $this->path_img = $this->path_cnfg->root_path.'/img/';
}
```

B. In **obj.php** you transfer that variables from object *$path* to array **$data**.

```
$data['path_img'] = $path->path_img;//Assign image directory path
$data['path_root'] = $config->root_path;//Assign root path
$data['url_base'] = $config->base_url;//Assign base url
$data['url_css'] = $path->url_css;//Assign css directory path
$data['url_js'] = $path->url_js;//Assign javascript directory path
$data['url_img'] = $path->url_img;//Assign url for image
```

What was purpose of having class *Path* over defining array **$data** by itself and use it derectly? Why we need to go trough all this methods and object to get to same variable ($data) that we could originally defined in 6 lines of code.
e.g.

```
$data["path_img"] = $config->base_url . "assets/img/";
...
$data["url_css"] = $config->base_url . "/assets/css/"
$data["url_js"] = $config->base_url . "assets/js/"
$data["url_img"] = $config->base_url . "assets/img/"
```

Comment: Read the manual and/or any basic OOP tutorial. What kind of answer are you expecting here?

Comment: Why we need to go trough all this methods and object to get to same variable ($data) that we could originally defined in 6 lines of code.

Comment: This is old code. `Path` here is the constructor, not a method to be called normally.

Comment: yes i found that now in php constructor should be defined like this __construct() on top of class.

Comment: OOP stands for "Object Oriented Programming", so of course it's done with objects. But you can also use helper functions. And when a project reaches a certain level, you **need** to work OOP, otherwise it's very hard to keep track of everything.

Comment: @PetjaZaichikov: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: complaining about objects in OOP? That's like complaining your orange juice tastes like oranges...

Comment: Jon great that's what i wanted to know, create answer

Comment: Most (if not all) external PHP libraries now are supplied as classes, and PHP has been offering increasing amounts of OO functionality since version 5.0. I'd recommend looking into OOP, and learning about it, even if you are happy for your code to remain procedural. I think it is a widely held view that objects really do help build complex systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You choose object-oriented programming when encapsulating data and behavior into classes, whose instances, maps well onto the problem you're trying to solve.

Not *every* problem is best done with objects.  There are other styles of programming - functional and declarative come to mind - that are also good.  Most of the scientific programming that I know of is done using functional or procedural languages, not objects.

Object-oriented languages can be verbose when compared to functional styles.

If OOP does map well onto your problems, you need not program with objects.

I don't know much about objects in PHP, but I'd guess that they're an afterthought.  I wouldn't consider it in the top five languages for object-oriented programming.

Perhaps the problem has as much to do with you as it does the implementation or language.  It might seem strange if you're not used to thinking in terms of objects.

Comment: I am not thinking in terms of objects that's for sure. I understand if you could see that objects in 3d or 2d while designing not just classes with code then it could clear things up a bit.